# How to define function in a string in Android?

Tags: java, xml, android, string

I have an event handler that I want to be connected to a button through xml.

Basically, I want to define it as a string in my xml file, then use the property inspector to select the name of the handler for my button (the "on Click" property).

How do I define a call to the function in the string?

Comment: Could you please explain more about what you want to do? Do you want to use the string.xml file for localization (put the name of your button there and have the text change at runtime via getText?) or do you want to "define a function in the string" which, technically can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's "Easier click listeners" section here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html

Answer (score 0):

You <strike>can't</strike> **can** attach a function from XML.
What you do is create a layout, inflate it from Java code, find the button by id and attach a function that will be called on click.
This is covered in introductory tutorials.

EDIT:
As pointed out by Romain Guy, http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick
(but I'd say it's crazy anyways :))

Comment: Actually you can since Donut: android:onClick="myClickHandler" and you must have a public void myClickHandler(View v) method in your Activity.